# Combining multiple functions to single generic function

Tags: c++, code-readability

I have couple of function to initialise an interface pointer and each function initialise pointer for particular version. Now i have to make these functions into a single generic function.

```
bool init_9(MSTSCLib::IMsRdpClient9* iface)
{
    iface->putSomeData1();
    iface->putSomeData2();
    iface->putSomeData3();
} 

bool init_8(MSTSCLib::IMsRdpClient8* iface)
{
    iface->putSomeData2();
}

bool init_7(MSTSCLib::IMsRdpClient7* iface)
{
    iface->putSomeData1();
    iface->putSomeData3();
}
```

I want to know if there are any better implementation to below prototype because each statement would require explicit casting of interface pointer and also visual studio Intellisense will have hard time fetching details.

```
bool init(void* ptriface, int version)
{
    void* iface; // todo: make this type to required version

    // Cast iface at run-time according to version number
    // switch(version){}
    iface = reinterpret_cast<MSTSCLib::IMsRdpClient9*>(ptriface);
    iface = reinterpret_cast<MSTSCLib::IMsRdpClient8*>(ptriface);
    iface = reinterpret_cast<MSTSCLib::IMsRdpClient7*>(ptriface);

    // switch(version){}
    iface->putSomeData1();
    iface->putSomeData2();
    iface->putSomeData3();
    iface->putSomeData4();    
}
```

Comment: A template function maybe?

Comment: The logic is different for each type? Might as well keep the same function but with overloads

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're simply looking for function overloading:

```
bool init(MSTSCLib::IMsRdpClient9*);
bool init(MSTSCLib::IMsRdpClient8*);
bool init(MSTSCLib::IMsRdpClient7*);

bool init(MSTSCLib::IMsRdpClient9* iface)
{
    iface->putSomeData1();
    iface->putSomeData2();
    iface->putSomeData3();
} 

// ...
```